# Blink when switching from static position to fixed position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-position, skrollr

I have a page with an element that should stick to the top of the viewport when the top of the element hits it. I am using a plugin called Skrollr to accomplish this. The issue that I am having is when the element hits the top of the viewport and switches to `fixed` positioning the content within it appears to blink or shift. This only happens when I'm scrolling somewhat quickly. If I scroll slow it does not blink or shift.

Here is a jsfiddle with an example of the issue that I am seeing. I haven't tested any other browsers besides Chrome yet.

http://jsfiddle.net/dmcgrew/sYV6L/

Updated jsfiddle.. watch how the green block scrolls up past the top of the viewport slightly then jumps back down. This only happens when scrolling fast.. http://jsfiddle.net/dmcgrew/sYV6L/1/

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, its rescaling the div to the 100% width and rerendering to the viewport size. When in `position: static`, an element is within the DOM flow and will be bound by its parent element. When in `position: fixed` however, that parent => child relationship is broken, and the element is taken out of the DOM flow. This forces the browser to repaint the DOM without the element in the DOM flow.

This is why you get that minute flash and rescale. If this is going to be a problem, I would suggest using some sort of transition (jQuery animation etc) to ease it, or use a different plugin that doesn't force the window to be repainted.

Comment: I just updated the jsfiddle to show what happens when there's no margin on the body. The green element scrolls up past the top of the viewport then jumps back down. I'd like to stop it from doing that. http://jsfiddle.net/dmcgrew/sYV6L/1/

Comment: This plugin's demo is working perfectly, I don't see what its doing differently than what I'm doing through. *shrug* http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/

Comment: @DustinMcGrew Looking at your fiddle, its still an issue with changing an element from `position: static` to `position: fixed`. Youre forcing the browser to repaint the DOM flow, hence why you get the blink. I would suggest using the plugin you gave as an example, they seem to have figured out how to do it without needing to repaint the DOM itself.